# Django with Docker stuck on "Watching for file changes with StatReloader"

Tags: python, django, docker

This is my code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig87i.jpg

When I run "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" it works perfectly fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX13T.jpg

But when I use docker with "make compose-start" it doesnt work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8vpZ.jpg

Im trying to follow a python tutorial and cannot progress without fixing this. It just hangs there.

What do I do? Is something wrong? Anything else I could screenshot to help?

EDIT: Apparently the server is up and running as it hangs there at "Watching for file changes with StatReloader". The website runs. However its supposed to look like this in the terminal,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCgGb.jpg

Is this a non-issue and theres nothing wrong?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding this line to the Dockerfile:

`ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`

like the Django example on [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/)

Comment: Right. It's works for me.
But what is the resaon to add this env variable ?

Answer (score 14):

try adding `tty: true` to your docker-compose.

```
services:
  web:
    tty: true
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

Comment: Telling python not to write the byte code would make it slower, but how would it help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using latest python solved it for me

only change I made was

`FROM python:3`

to

`FROM python`

my full Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM python
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```